# jQuery "exists" function with callback

Tags: callback, jquery-callback, jquery

Extending: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31047/235633

Is there a way I can extend this custom jQuery function to use a callback? Essentially I want to be able to have a list of selectors and detect their existence and if they exist, I need to show them.

Instead of writing a thousand if statements, I rather write one function that uses a callback and 'this'.

The guy wrote:

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}

if ($(selector).exists()) {
    // Do something
}
```

But I need:

```
$('.selector1, .selector2, .selector3').exists(function({
    $(this).show();
});
```

Comment: just use a single if statement around the whole thing.

Comment: Did you want to only show them if all three existed, else not show any of them?

Answer (score 3):

jQuery will loop through them for you.

```
$('.selector1, .selector2, .selector3').show();
```

Should work as intended.

Answer (score 3):

So basically, you want to show the ones that exist? Then you don't need to :)

```
$('.selector1, .selector2, .selector3').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the general case you can use [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for this:

```
$('.selector1, .selector2, .selector3').each(function({
  //some work involving $(this) 
});
```

But in this case, [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) works on all matched elements anyway:

```
$('.selector1, .selector2, .selector3').show();
```